# Progressive difficulty of leveling up skills - or not? (TES3: Morrowind)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've looked on the UESP Wiki and extensively DuckDuckGo'd for the answer to this, to no avail.

In Oblivion and Skyrim, skills "level up"/increase progressively "slower" - e.g., you need to make more hits to go from "Random Weapon" 99 to 100 than you need for 9 to 10.

However, as far as I can tell, Morrowind has each level require 100 "points", which are given statically (e.g., most weapons add 1 point per successful hit). Am I not seeing something, or is it really 100 hits to go from "Random Weapon" 9 to 10 and equally so 100 hits to go from "Random Weapon" 99 to 100?

Comment: related read: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Level

Comment: @Zommuter
Sure, only that article almost exclusively deals with "character levels" and not so much skill ones. In fact, when it comes to game mechanics, the Morrowind section has some way to go to reach the level of the Oblivion section. The OpenMW page linked to in the answer is faring quite a bit better in this regard.

Comment: precisely, I just thought it worth mentioning as a comment "for the interested reader" :-7 (That's why I upvoted the answer instead of posting a new). I see you're new here, so: Welcome to the Arqade :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Morrowind skill progression slows down linearly while Oblivion and Skyrim use exponential formula.

---

A lot of underlying math behind the game can be found on [this OpenMW project page](https://wiki.openmw.org/index.php?title=Research:Stats_and_Levelling#Skill_progress). According to their research,

```
Progress = Base gain / ((Level + 1) * Type bonus * Specialization bonus)
```

`Progress` – progress through a skill level (from 0 to 1) from single successful action.

`Level` – current level of the skill.

`Base gain` – skill increase factor that depends on skill and action (e.g. for Alchemy and Potion Creation it is 2.0).

`Type bonus` – bonus based on the skill type:

- Major skill – 0.75
- Minor skill – 1.0
- Misc skill – 1.25

`Specialization bonus` – 0.8 if the player has the same specialization (combat/magic/stealth) as the skill, or 1.0 if not.

Comment: Wow, OpenMW has come a long way since I last checked...

Comment: That's precisely the information I was looking for. Thank you!